# how to procedurally create Mesh on a 3d shape along all axis like paper.io 3d in UNITY?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, mesh

Right now we are storing our last position as vertices in a list, forming the triangles based on the vertices Array/List, the mesh forms correctly but the generated mesh overlaps with shapes mesh and makes some portions of the newly generated mesh non-visible, when we uplift the mesh Gameobject little bit from the unity editor we can see the missing parts are there but its inside of our shape that's why we can't see it.

Need help procedurally generating the mesh on the shape's circumference so that it won't overlap the shape's original mesh and the newly generated mesh fits perfectly on top of the shape's actual mesh-like paper.io3d.

Right now we are generating the triangles using this code:

```cs
public class TriangulatorT
{
    private Vector3[] vertices;

    public TriangulatorT(Vector3[] vertices)
    {
        this.vertices = vertices;
    }

    public int[] Triangulate()
    {
        int[] indices = new int[(vertices.Length - 2) * 3];
        int index = 0;

        for (int i = 2; i < vertices.Length; i++)
        {
            indices[index++] = 0;
            indices[index++] = i - 1;
            indices[index++] = i;
        }

        return indices;
    }
}
```